# Finding average max and min temp for each month of input year

Tags: c++, arrays, stream

I am currently new to C++ (and programming in general) and have been struggling with various problems. The current one I can not figure out for the life of me goes like this:

There is a file (we're practicing file stream) that has temperatures for every single day from 1990 to 2010 for New Orleans. There are 3 columns, date, max temp of that day, and min temp of that day. The goal of the code is to use arrays and file streams so that the user inputs a year, and the max and min temp average is printed for each month. What I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int const yearDivisor = 10000;
int const voidTemp = -9999;

void monthlyAverageTemperature(ifstream &inFile, ostream &outFile) {
    int date = 0;
    int minTemp = 0;
    int maxTemp = 0;
    int sum1[12];
    int sum2[12];
    int count1[12];
    int count2[12];
    int inputYear;
    double maxMonthTemp[12];
    double minMonthTemp[12];

    cout << "Input a year to average max and min temps:";
    cin >> inputYear;

    while(inFile >> date >> maxTemp >> minTemp) {
        int calcDate = static_cast<int>(date) / yearDivisor;
        if(maxTemp != voidTemp && minTemp != voidTemp && inputYear == calcDate) {
            
            for (int i = 0; i<=12; i++) {
                sum1[i] = sum1[i] + maxTemp;
                sum2[i] = sum2[i] + minTemp;
                count1[i]++;
                count2[i]++;
                double average1 = static_cast<double>(sum1[i]) / count1[i];
                double average2 = static_cast<double>(sum2[i]) / count2[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what to do so that it calculates each month's average and I literally have no clue where to go from here. I also know that the calculation for month is

```cpp
month = (date - calcDate * yearDivisor) / 100
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Generally you shouldn't tag a a question as both C and C++ unless you're certain it applies to both. This does not. This is C++ code. 2) Make sure your code is properly formatted before posting it.

Comment: You calculate the average min and max the same way you would any other average - you sum the values and then divide by the number of values. So for min you would iterate through the values for a month, adding them, and then divide by the number of values you iterated.

Comment: Note: Spacing the `++` off of the thing it's incrementing is misleading and confusing.

Comment: Tip: Instead of a bunch of array variables, use an array of a `struct` with multiple properties. `std::vector` is a huge help here. `std::sort` can help give min/max values. Also use `x += y` instead of `x = x + y`.

Comment: Note: `average1` and `average2` get thrown into the trash right after they're assigned.

Comment: @tadman This is the academic practice of teaching "parallel arrays" prior to teaching user-defined types.

Comment: @Casey Like a lot of "academic practices" it's horrible and needs to stop. If you can handle arrays, you can handle `struct` with like a half hour of explanation and it will save you a world of hurt.

Comment: @tadman True, but it can also be a lead-up to [SoA vs AoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA)...if the instructor even knows that's a thing.

Comment: You can maintain a *running maximum*, without using a container.  As each value is read, update the maximum value as necessary.  Same with minimum.  Also, you can compute the sums in the same loop.